# "(Empty)" text "literally" instead of "" in datacolumn from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005, dataset

I've always have a problem with big datasets created through the dataset designer in visual studio (2005). When the dataset many tables with many columns, the columns defined like "(Empty)" in the NULL VALUE property starts showing the text "(Empty)" literally.

Is anyone aware of this? or is just me?

Thanks in advance.